# How to limit mouse cursor into a rectangle in Qt environment (in Ubuntu 12.04, not Windows)

Tags: qt, ubuntu, cursor, mouse

there is a question confuse me a few days, that is how can I limit mouse cursor into a rectangle in Qt environment? And my OS is ubuntu 12.04, so Windows API ClipCursor() doesn't work. thank you very much.

Comment: And I do it as flows: when the cursor close to the rectangle edge, I call setPos() function let the cursor move to previous position, but the effect is not very good, when the cursor close the edge, it jitter hard.

Comment: Rather than check when it is close to the edge, check if it is on or past the edge, the set it on the edge.

Comment: thank you. But it always jitter hard. Do you have better method? thank you.

Comment: I suggest you edit the question and show the code of how you are handling this.

Comment: I'd strongly advise to try finding another solution. As a user I'd hate having my cursor movements restricted

Comment: @Bowdzone This is the requirement of our project, and it must restrict mouse cursor into a rectangle. thank you. do you have other solution?

Answer (score 0):

this involving `QGraphicsItem::itemChange()`. If you have an item which you want to restrict to a certain area then reimplement `itemChange()` for that item and monitor `QGraphicsItem::ItemPositionHasChanged` changes to see whether the items wants to be placed outside your area of interest and prevent that by returning a position from inside that area. for example:

```
    QVariant QGraphicsItem::itemChange(GraphicsItemChange change, const QVariant &value)
{
    switch (change) {
    case ItemPositionHasChanged:
        if(x() < -200 || y() < -200 || x() > 200 || y() > 200)
            setPos(0, 0);
        graph->itemMoved();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    };

    return QGraphicsItem::itemChange(change, value);
}
```

If you don't have an item but rather want to force a user to click within the area then hide the mouse pointer (by setting it to a blank shape), create a dedicated item that will serve as a cursor, optionally grab the mouse to that shape and then use `itemChange()` like I described earlier.